# Is it normal for Postfix to store old messages in mbox when Maildir is active?

Tags: email, postfix, maildir

I noticed this output when testing my first Postfix installation:

```
Saved 1 message in /home/USERNAME/mbox
Held 1 message in /home/USERNAME/Maildir
```

I have home_mailbox or whatever set to "Maildir/", so I was not expecting to see mbox anywhere after setting that up. Is this expected behavior or did I overlooks something during the installation?

Comment: It may be message delivered BEFORE switching to maildir,  Take a look at `/home/USERNAME/mbox` file.

Comment: I'll take a look in there and see what I can see. It's happening every time I open mail, read a message, and quit :(